# Delphi's TNetHTTPClient descendant supporting http2

Tags: delphi, grpc, http2

I am trying to communicate with Google Cloud Speech via gRPC from a Delphi 10.3.1 Windows client application. For this, the communication needs to be using http2 as protocol, and data needs to be transmitted 2-ways async.

Delphi includes TNetHTTPClient, which is used by TNetHTTPRequest for http communication. Using the debugger, I found that TWinHTTPClient in System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas is used internally for the communication.

To add http2 support, I inserted 2 lines in TWinHTTPClient.DoExecuteRequest in System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas, at line 1360:

```
    LOptionValue := 1;//WINHTTP_PROTOCOL_FLAG_HTTP2;
    WinHttpSetOption(LRequest.FWRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_ENABLE_HTTP_PROTOCOL, @LOptionValue, sizeof(LOptionValue));
```

After adding the above code, the component is using http2, which I verified by calling Google Cloud Speech Sync Request endpoint via gRPC successfully.

However, my approach has two major disadvantages:

1. It needs Delphi Source Code modification.
2. It does not support async bidirectional transport of data, for which I think an event a la OnDataReceived that may be triggered without the connection being closed is necessary.

I tried to find a point where I could replace TNetHTTPClient by a modified component TMyNetHTTPClient, but I did not succeed.

So, the question is: how to create a TNetHTTPClient replacement, based on TWinHTTPClient, that supports http2 and implements OnDataReceived event without closing the connection?

Comment: "*how to create a TNetHTTPClient replacement, based on TWinHTTPClient, that supports http2 and implements OnDataReceived event without closing the connection?*" - you can't. Why not just use the WinHTTP API directly instead?

Comment: So, it is impossible to create a TNetHTTPClient descendant that implements the requested features? Disappointing, as to me, Delphi's TNetHTTPRequest/TNetHTTPClient seem to be designed as easy-to-use wrappers around WinHTTP API.

Comment: You can create a descendant. Just write the code that wraps the appropriate WinHTTP calls to support http2. What's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: I was unable to create a TWinHTTPClient descendant, as that is in implementation section of System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas. I tried to create a TNetHTTPClient descendant, but I was unable to override DoExecuteRequest with TWinHttpClient.DoExecuteRequest.

Comment: Basically, what is stopping me is: the unclear relation between TNetHttpClient and TWinHTTPClient.

Comment: Maybe other developers are waiting also for this RTL extension in Delphi.  I have created today the following feature request in RSP-32222: Missing HTTP2 protocol support in THTTPClient

Answer (score 0):

It's not based on TNetHTTPClient, but grijjy have open-sourced an HTTP2 Delphi client for Windows and Linux.

You can find it here - https://github.com/grijjy/DelphiScalableClientSockets

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, sorry :)
I don't know how to implement the async bidirectional transport of data. I do know how TWinHTTPClient is constructed. Unfortunately, as you found out, since TWinHTTPClient is hidden in the unit's implementation, you cannot extend it.

You could copy that unit, make the necessary modifications, and use the modified class instead. It's not ideal at all to copy it, since it's a unit of over 2000 lines, but unfortunately there is no way around that.

But how to construct the modified TWinHttpClient, since normally you wouldn't construct a TWinHttpClient directly at all? That's a bit tricky, especially if you want to use other classes (like TNetHttpClient), that construct their own HttpClient internally.

TWinHTTPClient registers itself as a handler for `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. The unit itself does that by invoking `TUrlSchemas.RegisterURLClientScheme`.

You could unregister the TWinHttpClient class, and register your own like so:

```
  TURLSchemes.UnRegisterURLClientScheme('HTTP');
  TURLSchemes.UnRegisterURLClientScheme('HTTPS');
  TURLSchemes.RegisterURLClientScheme(TYourWinHttpClient, 'HTTP');
  TURLSchemes.RegisterURLClientScheme(TYourWinHttpClient, 'HTTPS');
```

After that, you can call THttpClient.Create, which is actually not a constructor but a *class function* that will invoke `TURLSchemes` to get an instance of the registered class.

That is, it finds the class, and calls the `CreateInstance` class function of that class. CreateInstance is a virtual factory method of TUrlClient, the ultimate base class. Your class should override that method to create and return an instance of itself.

It's a freaky construction. THttpClient is not just the base class for the various platform-specific descendants, but it's also a factory for them.
I happened to bump into this logic (and this question), when I was trying to create a THttpClient descendant for unit-testing purposes and ran into some surprise behavior. I'm not yet sure if it's genius or madness, or both :D

`TUrlClient`, `THttpClient` and `TWinHttpClient` are RTL classes, meant to be instantiated from code.

`TNetHTTPClient` is a TComponent that you can place on a TForm or TDataModule to configure design time. At runtime, when making requests, it uses THttpClient internally. It *should* use your modified version if you register it.